# Is take care proper for this picture?

Tags: meaning, idioms, synonyms

I want to know the difference between *look out*, *take care*, and *watch out*.

[image]

Comment: It is a page of English book

Comment: Please look  the new image

Comment: Simple answer: No. But this post has been closed. Perhaps if you remove reference to the sign completely and just need clarification of what the similar phrases mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No differences can be seen between `look out` and `watch out`, yet `take care` is quite different.
`Watch out` is the best, I believe. There are also many other choices like `Cautious`. Still I assume `watch out` is the best.

Comment: Thank you     this picture is in a English book   can we say it is incorrect?

Comment: It's incorrect. There, I said it. I'd say "Heads up" to warn someone *right now* of danger. "Take care" is too general for this picture. How can I take care (in looking where I'm going) to watch out for a maniac throwing things at me from behind?

Comment: Thanks a lot  for your response

Comment: "Heads up" is the last thing you should shout if someone needs to duck.

Answer (score 0):

No. Take care implies behavior that improves ones wellbeing over an extended period.
Look out and watch out are synonymous, and urge taking immediate action to avoid an accident.